# Refresh sheet when date entered in cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

In the upper part of my Excel sheet I can put in two keywords via a dropdown menu (Cell D9). Below that I can enter a date (Cell D19).

In the lower part of the Excel sheet are multiple lists of the twelve months that are split by the two keywords. There are multiple of the same list for keyword 1 and 2.

I want when I choose one of the keywords that the lists for the other keywords are hidden.
In addition I want months in the list that are before the entered date hidden.

ChatGPT gave me code. The only problem is that when I enter a certain date and then enter a date that is before the original date, the sheet does not refresh.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dateToCompare As Date
    Dim cell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eingabe") ' Change "Eingabe" to your sheet name
    Set iCell = Intersect(Range("D9"), Target)

    ' Handle "Strom" and "Gas" functionality
    If Not iCell Is Nothing Then
        If iCell.Value = "Strom" Then
            ' Adjust these ranges to match your data
            ws.Rows("23:61").Hidden = False
            ws.Rows("62:100").Hidden = True
        ElseIf iCell.Value = "Gas" Then
            ' Adjust these ranges to match your data
            ws.Rows("23:61").Hidden = True
            ws.Rows("62:100").Hidden = False
        'Else ' do nothing
        End If
    End If

    ' Check for dates in column C and hide rows if the date is earlier than D19
    dateToCompare = ws.Range("D19").Value
    For Each cell In ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not cell.EntireRow.Hidden Then ' Check if the row is not already hidden
            If IsDate(cell.Value) And cell.Value < dateToCompare Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this row `If Not cell.EntireRow.Hidden Then ' Check if the row is not already hidden` plus the corresponding `End If` - then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried that and you are right now the thing with the date works. But now if I select the second keyword the rows corresponding to the first keyword are not hidden any more. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: then you have to check for all conditions in one IF-statement

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I have never worked with VBA before :(

Comment: Why not add a column that says "Gas" or "Strom" and then use a filter to filter the sheet on both the date column and the new column?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are making the selections and then running the macro every time correct? It's not like you have it set to automatically run?

If this is the case.. the easiest solution might be to make a second macro to "reset" the page back to the default. (Though now that I am writing this I think it's easier to just add it to the beginning of your current one -- but the logic of two separate macros probably makes the logic easier to understand -- for me at least! :-) )

In "non-technical terms" (I understand you are new to VBA) what I am suggesting is that... what is causing your problem is: Once the data is filtered one way... certain parts get stuck that way depending on future changes to the inputs. If, after (or before) each input change you "reset" the file to it's original, unfiltered version this would not be a problem!

In your specific example, I THINK (could be missing something) but the only thing to "reset" is whether or not columns are hidden.

If you simply add:

`ws.Rows("1:100").Hidden = False`

right before where you currently have the comment/line:

`' Handle "Strom" and "Gas" functionality`

And you should be all set!